# Retrieve Data from TCP Server device

Tags: .net, serial-port

Good Day Everyone
This is more a "Is it possible, and if so how?" question.
We have a couple of serial-to-ip devices on our network that have RS485 devices connected to them. We use westemo serial to IP converters, if that helps. Is it possible to "ping" the serial devices connected to the IP device? The function would be only to check if they are alive from a client point-of-view. I have no programming language specifically in mind but .NET would be preferred.
If anyone could point me in the right direction on where to start reading or looking around I would appreciate it. Yes I have asked Google but nothing really pops up.
Thanks
Have a great new year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as serial devices don't send data, you won't be able to "see" them.

Your serial-to-ip device has probably a **Raw TCP mode**, i.e. you can make a simple TCP socket connection and send a command your serial device would understand and answer. This way you know a serial device is attached to your serial-to-ip device and is working. See this [tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/kb5kfec7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on how to make a TCP connection in C# or VB.net.

You can also use the **virtual serial COM port** function to open a COM port and send a command as you would with COM1. See this [tutorial](http://csharp.simpleserial.com/).